# Put the batteries,take out,out it back in

Tags: word-usage

If a remote control has no batteries in it,is it natural to say:

> I have to **put the batteries** in the remote control. (Or should it be : I have to **insert the batteries** in)

And if we remove the batteries,

> I took the batteries **out of the remote** control.

And if some removes the batteries that are working, is it natural to say:

> Hey,**put them back** in.

(**And similarly  if someone inserts dead batteries back into the remote,is it natural to say: Take them back out!**)

Are my sentences natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Put the batteries in*** and ***take the batteries out*** are natural and idiomatic to me. ***Insert*** and to a lesser extent ***remove*** seem more formal, but that just makes them less likely to be used in everyday speech. They are the words that are used in written instructions, generally.

Your instructions to people to put batteries back in or take them out are perfectly good English, but depending on tone, context, and audience may be seen as rude, or at least as annoyed.

Comment: And is it natural  to say: There are no batteries in the remote control.

Comment: Yes, that's natural. Well, it's more natural to use the ungrammatical contraction, "there's no batteries in the remote control", but the uncontracted form is fine.

Comment: And what do you think about "adding batteries"? "I've to add batteries to the remote."

Answer (score 0):

Both *put* and *insert* are fine, although I think **insert** feels better and more suitable.
Instead of **"took out"**, you could simply use "*remove*", but *took out* is also fine.

And yes, your sentences seem natural and alright.